# How to recreate the table by key?

Tags: r, data.table

I thought it could be a very easy question, but I am really a new beginner  for R.

I have a `data.table` with key and lots of rows, two of which could be set as key. I want to recreate the table by Key.

For example, the simple data. In this case, the key is `ID` and `Act`, and here we can get a total of 4 groups.

```
ID  ValueDate Act Volume
1 2015-01-01 EUR     21
1 2015-02-01 EUR     22
1 2015-01-01 MAD     12
1 2015-02-01 MAD     11
2 2015-01-01 EUR      5
2 2015-02-01 EUR      7
3 2015-01-01 EUR      4
3 2015-02-01 EUR      2
3 2015-03-01 EUR      6
```

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
dd <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
             ValueDate = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01"),
             Act = c("EUR","EUR","MAD","MAD","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR"),
             Volume=c(21,22,12,11,5,7,4,2,6))
```

After change, each column should present a specific group which is defined by Key (`ID` and `Act`).

Below is the result:

```
 ValueDate ID1_EUR D1_MAD D2_EUR D3_EUR
 2015-01-01      21     12      5      4
 2015-02-01      22     11      7      2
 2015-03-01      NA     NA     NA      6
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not recreating the data.table, but reshaping it from a long format to a wide format. You can use `dcast` for this:

```
dcast(dd, ValueDate ~ ID + Act, value.var = "Volume")
```

which gives:

```
    ValueDate 1_EUR 1_MAD 2_EUR 3_EUR
1: 2015-01-01    21    12     5     4
2: 2015-02-01    22    11     7     2
3: 2015-03-01    NA    NA    NA     6
```

If you want the numbers in the resulting columns to be preceded with `ID`, then you can use:

```
dcast(dd, ValueDate ~ paste0("ID",ID) + Act, value.var = "Volume")
```

which gives:

```
    ValueDate ID1_EUR ID1_MAD ID2_EUR ID3_EUR
1: 2015-01-01      21      12       5       4
2: 2015-02-01      22      11       7       2
3: 2015-03-01      NA      NA      NA       6
```